# I'm using the CountDownLatch of JUC,but my app is blocked

Tags: java

I'm learning JUC,I want to calculate the total time that the program runs with five threads,but it's blocked after print "1 2 3"。please tell me what the reason is ？
   In addition, if I don't call the function "isPrime(int)",The program will execute normally.

```
public class TestCountDownLatch {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     CountDownLatch cwt = new CountDownLatch(5);
     Runnable runnable = new CountDownThread(cwt);
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         new Thread(runnable).start();
     }
     try {
         cwt.await();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("total time :" + (end - start));
    }
}



class CountDownThread implements Runnable{

private CountDownLatch countdownLatch;

private int num = 1;

public CountDownThread(CountDownLatch countdownLatch) {
    this.countdownLatch = countdownLatch;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        while(true){
            synchronized (this) {
                if(num > 100){
                    break;
                }
                if(isPrime(num)){
                    System.out.println(num++);
                }
            }
        }
    }finally{
        countdownLatch.countDown();
    }

}


private boolean isPrime(int i) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= (i >> 1); j++) {
        if(i % j == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Runnable` run method, is only incrementing `num` when its prime and hence when it encounters `4` which is not prime its not incrementing `num` and your program is in that state for rest of period when its running. Fiddled with below mentioned piece which makes it go beyond that point and break at `100`.

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                num++; // initially assigning int num = 0, and then doing this
                if (num > 100) {
                    break;
                }
                if (isPrime(num)) {
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        countdownLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mate, that's not stupid, trust me we all have done that. I'm most welcome that I could be of use there